# Creating an Esper long running process or service

Tags: service, daemon, esper

I'd like to create an [Esper](http://esper.codehaus.org/) engine long running process but I'm not sure of Esper's threading model nor the model I should implement to do this. Naively I tried the following:

```
public class EsperTest {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //EPServiceProvider epService = EPServiceProviderManager.getDefaultProvider();
   EPServiceProvider epService = EPServiceProviderManager.getProvider("CoreEngine");
   epService.addServiceStateListener(new EPServiceStateListener() {

       @Override
       public void onEPServiceDestroyRequested(EPServiceProvider epsp) {
           System.out.println("Service destroyed");
       }

       @Override
       public void onEPServiceInitialized(EPServiceProvider epsp) {
           System.out.println("System initialised");
       }
   });

   epService.initialize();
}
```

}

But the code appears to execute to the end of the `main()` method and the JVM ends.

Referring to the Esper documentation, section 14.7 p456:

> In the default configuration, each engine instance maintains a single timer thread (internal timer)
>   providing for time or schedule-based processing within the engine. The default resolution at which
>   the internal timer operates is 100 milliseconds. The internal timer thread can be disabled and
>   applications can instead send external time events to an engine instance to perform timer or
>   scheduled processing at the resolution required by an application.

Consequently I thought that by creating a an engine instance ("CoreEngine") at least one (timer) thread would be created and assuming this is not a daemon thread the `main()` method would not complete but this appears not to be the case.

Do I have to implement my own infinite loop in `main()` or is there a configuration which can be provided to Esper which will allow it to run 'forever.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timer threads is a daemon thread.
Instead of a loop use a latch like this.

```
final CountDownLatch shutdownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        shutdownLatch.countDown();
    }
});
shutdownLatch.await();
```